# Beginner: Adding a Teleport Room to World Of Zuul

Tags: java

I have a compsci lab in which we must complete the text adventure game "World of Zuul". To do this we had to complete several steps such as creating more rooms, creating an items class, and adding items to rooms. The final step is to add a Teleport room to the game. Here is the text from the project sheet:

> Implement a “teleport room” that has an entrance but no exit.  The
>   short description is “in a room with blank walls and no obvious exit”.
>   When you perform the look command in the teleport room, there is a 75%
>   chance that you will just stay in the teleport room and see the
>   description above.  There is a 25% chance that you will teleport
>   randomly into one of the other N rooms and then you will see a
>   description of that room.  You will need to think about re-organizing
>   the relationship between the Room class and the Game class to make
>   this happen.

I can't figure out how to do this. Any help is much appreciated.

**Room Class:**

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

/**
 * Class Room - a room in an adventure game.
 *
 * This class is part of the "World of Zuul" application. 
 * "World of Zuul" is a very simple, text based adventure game.  
 *
 * A "Room" represents one location in the scenery of the game.  It is 
 * connected to other rooms via exits.  For each existing exit, the room 
 * stores a reference to the neighboring room.
 * 
 * @author  Michael KÃ¶lling and David J. Barnes
 * @version 2011.08.08
 */

public class Room 
{
    private String description;
    private HashMap<String, Room> exits;        // stores exits of this room.
    private HashSet<Item> items;

    /**
     * Create a room described "description". Initially, it has
     * no exits. "description" is something like "a kitchen" or
     * "an open court yard".
     * @param description The room's description.
     */
    public Room(String description) 
    {
        this.description = description;
        exits = new HashMap<String, Room>();
        items = new HashSet<Item>();
    }

    /**
     * Define an exit from this room.
     * @param direction The direction of the exit.
     * @param neighbor  The room to which the exit leads.
     */
    public void setExit(String direction, Room neighbor) 
    {
        exits.put(direction, neighbor);
    }

    /**
     * Add items into a room
     * @param item The item which will be added to the room
     */
    public void addItem(Item item)
    {
        items.add(item);
    }

    /**
     * @return The short description of the room
     * (the one that was defined in the constructor).
     */
    public String getShortDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * Return a description of the room in the form:
     *     You are in the kitchen.
     *     Exits: north west
     * @return A long description of this room
     */
    public String getLongDescription()
    {
        return "You are " + description + ".\n" + getExitString() + "\n" + getItemString();
    }

    /**
     * Return a string describing the room's exits, for example
     * "Exits: north west".
     * @return Details of the room's exits.
     */
    private String getExitString()
    {
        String returnString = "Exits:";
        Set<String> keys = exits.keySet();
        for(String exit : keys) {
            returnString += " " + exit;
        }
        return returnString;
    }

    /**
     * Return a string describing the room's items and descriptions, for example
     * "Items: Book, (insert description here".
     * @return Details of the room's items.
     */
    private String getItemString()
    {
        String itemString = "items: "; 
        if(items.size() < 1) {
            itemString = itemString += "There are no items here.";
        }
        else {
            for(Item item : items) {
                itemString+= item.getName() + "; " + item.getDescription() + ". ";
            }
        }
        return itemString;
    }

    /**
     * Return the room that is reached if we go from this room in direction
     * "direction". If there is no room in that direction, return null.
     * @param direction The exit's direction.
     * @return The room in the given direction.
     */
    public Room getExit(String direction) 
    {
        return exits.get(direction);
    }
}
```

**Game Class:**

```
public class Game 
{
    private Parser parser;
    private Room currentRoom;

    /*
     * Create the game and initialise its internal map.
     */
    public Game() 
    {
        createRooms();
        parser = new Parser();
    }

    /**
     * Create all the rooms and link their exits together.
     */
    private void createRooms()
    {
        Room outside, theater, pub, lab, office, labyrinth, teleport_room;
        Item book, stick, knife, spoon;

        // create the rooms
        outside = new Room("outside the main entrance of the university");
        theater = new Room("in a lecture theater");
        pub = new Room("in the campus pub");
        lab = new Room("in a computing lab");
        office = new Room("in the computing admin office");
        labyrinth = new Room("in the University Labyrinth");
        teleport_room = new Room("in a room with blank walls and no obvious exit");

        //create the items
        book = new Item("Book", "A book containing useless information", 5);
        stick = new Item("Stick", "A large stick, can be used for protection", 10);
        knife = new Item("Knife", "A dull butter knife", 5);
        spoon = new Item("Spoon", "A tablespoon, good for consumption of cereal", 5);

        // initialise room exits
        outside.setExit("east", theater);
        outside.setExit("south", lab);
        outside.setExit("west", pub);
        outside.setExit("north", labyrinth);

        theater.setExit("west", outside);

        pub.setExit("east", outside);
        pub.setExit("west", labyrinth);

        lab.setExit("north", outside);
        lab.setExit("east", office);

        office.setExit("west", lab);
        office.setExit("north", teleport_room);

        labyrinth.setExit("south", pub);
        labyrinth.setExit("east", outside);

        //initialize room items
        outside.addItem(book);
        labyrinth.addItem(stick);
        lab.addItem(knife);
        office.addItem(spoon);

        currentRoom = outside;  // start game outside
    }

    /**
     *  Main play routine.  Loops until end of play.
     */
    public void play() 
    {            
        printWelcome();

        // Enter the main command loop.  Here we repeatedly read commands and
        // execute them until the game is over.

        boolean finished = false;
        while (! finished) {
            Command command = parser.getCommand();
            finished = processCommand(command);
        }
        System.out.println("Thank you for playing.  Good bye.");
    }

    /**
     * Print out the opening message for the player.
     */
    private void printWelcome()
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Welcome to the World of Zuul!");
        System.out.println("World of Zuul is a new, incredibly boring adventure game.");
        System.out.println("Type 'help' if you need help.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(currentRoom.getLongDescription());
    }

    /**
     * Given a command, process (that is: execute) the command.
     * @param command The command to be processed.
     * @return true If the command ends the game, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean processCommand(Command command) 
    {
        boolean wantToQuit = false;

        if(command.isUnknown()) {
            System.out.println("I don't know what you mean...");
            return false;
        }

        String commandWord = command.getCommandWord();
        if (commandWord.equals("help")) {
            printHelp();
        }
        else if (commandWord.equals("go")) {
            goRoom(command);
        }
        else if (commandWord.equals("look")) {
            System.out.println(currentRoom.getLongDescription());
        }
        else if (commandWord.equals("quit")) {
            wantToQuit = quit(command);
        }
        // else command not recognised.
        return wantToQuit;
    }

    // implementations of user commands:

    /**
     * Print out some help information.
     * Here we print some stupid, cryptic message and a list of the 
     * command words.
     */
    private void printHelp() 
    {
        System.out.println("You are lost. You are alone. You wander");
        System.out.println("around at the university.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your command words are:");
        parser.showCommands();
    }

    /** 
     * Try to in to one direction. If there is an exit, enter the new
     * room, otherwise print an error message.
     */
    private void goRoom(Command command) 
    {
        if(!command.hasSecondWord()) {
            // if there is no second word, we don't know where to go...
            System.out.println("Go where?");
            return;
        }

        String direction = command.getSecondWord();

        // Try to leave current room.
        Room nextRoom = currentRoom.getExit(direction);

        if (nextRoom == null) {
            System.out.println("There is no door!");
        }
        else {
            currentRoom = nextRoom;
            System.out.println(currentRoom.getLongDescription());
        }
    }

    /** 
     * "Quit" was entered. Check the rest of the command to see
     * whether we really quit the game.
     * @return true, if this command quits the game, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean quit(Command command) 
    {
        if(command.hasSecondWord()) {
            System.out.println("Quit what?");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;  // signal that we want to quit
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to create a class "TeleporterRoom" that inherits from "Room"
Then you overwrite the method "getExit" in your new Class. This is where you calculate the probability of changing to another room.

Comment: How would I go about calculating probability? How about which room to end up in randomly?

Comment: Since the room has 4 possible exits, you can calculate your probability with that. Each exit has a probability of 25% (100/4), but if you only have 1 exit in your teleporter room, then you can randomly choose the direction (north, east, south or west) and then you have a 75% percent change to stay in the room because there is no exit.

Comment: What if I make no exit. I want the action of exiting to happen 25% of the time when i use a command called 'look'. So the room will have no exits, and 25% of the time that i say 'look' i'll leave, 75% of the time I won't.

Comment: you could do that with Math.random and a switch case. Just generate a random number between 0-3. then If "0" --> change room, else, do stuff.